# Ruby on Rails, internalization in coffescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, internationalization, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I have a coffeescript file for one of my resources. It seems like internalization doesn't work properly in my coffescript file. I want I18 gem to transform 'select' script, but it doesn't work.

coffeescript:

```
console.log('employee loaded -> '+"<%= I18n.t 'select' %>")
```

When I open the browser console I end up with this text:

```
employee loaded -> <%= I18n.t 'select' %>
```

en.yml

```
en:
    select: 'Select...'
```

tr.yml

```
tr:
    select: 'Seçiniz...'
```

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add extension?
filename.coffee.**erb**